# 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' When Using microsoft enterprise library 4.1 in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, enterprise-library

I am using VS2010 and .Net 4.00.

I have install microsoft enterprise library 4.1 in one of my Project.

I am getting below error:

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: The error message explains the most common problem. You *haven't* added the appropriate assembly to the project's references. Or you tried to use `Practices` as if it were a type, eg `Practices t;` or `using Practices;`. Post your code.

Comment: Basically error in Global.asax file where i am referencing                        <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling" %>

Comment: Have you *added the assembly reference to the project*? The `Import` tag adds a namespace, not a reference

Comment: Yes i have added Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHa‌​ndling,Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHa‌​ndling.Logging,Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging , Microsoft.Practices.Unity,Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration,Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation dll reference to project.